# Что нужно отправлять в photos.saveMessagesPhoto в качестве photo?

Tags: vkontakte-api

Получаю через `photos.getMessagesUploadServer` ссылку на загрузку фото, отправляю на ссылку файл, получаю такие данные

```
server -> 638518
hash -> "817a80b1e52c4860d679e996de5a5371"
photo -> "[\"photo\":\"d3a90575cb:w\"]" "photo":"[\"sizes\":[[\"s\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e2c\"]" "photo":"[\"fLWDQck0GGU\"]" "photo":"[56]" "photo":"[75]]" "photo":"[[\"m\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e2d\"]" "photo":"[\"TdcVw-PTrZ0\"]" "photo":"[97]" "photo":"[130]]" "photo":"[[\"x\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e2e\"]" "photo":"[\"E3C8Buuazz8\"]" "photo":"[453]" "photo":"[604]]" "photo":"[[\"y\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e2f\"]" "photo":"[\"Sg1QDLFZKbI\"]" "photo":"[605]" "photo":"[807]]" "photo":"[[\"z\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e30\"]" "photo":"[\"cx9R87nsiaA\"]" "photo":"[810]" "photo":"[1080]]" "photo":"[[\"w\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e31\"]" "photo":"[\"Vv28eWrIiAY\"]" "photo":"[1200]" "photo":"[1600]]" "photo":"[[\"o\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e32\"]" "photo":"[\"RrSUaPQfbp4\"]" "photo":"[130]" "photo":"[173]]" "photo":"[[\"p\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e33\"]" "photo":"[\"9Y9oyH6Gqok\"]" "photo":"[200]" "photo":"[267]]" "photo":"[[\"q\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e34\"]" "photo":"[\"hWhThkZIwBM\"]" "photo":"[320]" "photo":"[427]]" "photo":"[[\"r\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e35\"]" "photo":"[\"MR4kkUA21RQ\"]" "photo":"[510]" "photo":"[680]]]" "photo":"[\"kid\":\"973e1fa0db673b36d800371b81800000\"]" "photo":"[\"debug\":\"xswmwxwywzwwwowpwqwrw\"]"
```

Я вот смотрю на значение `photo` и просто не могу понять, что с ним не так, кавычки вроде закрываются после первой же `]` значит первый `photo` закончился, потом еще какой-то `photo`, массивы, кавычки, я вообще теряюсь. Передаю этот ужас в `photos.saveMessagesPhoto` и получаю вот такое

```
    {
"error": {
"error_code": 100,
"error_msg": "One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: photos_list is invalid",
"request_params": [{
"key": "oauth",
"value": "1"
}, {
"key": "method",
"value": "photos.saveMessagesPhoto"
}, {
"key": "hash",
"value": "817a80b1e52c4860d679e996de5a5371"
}, {
"key": "photo",
"value": "[\"photo\":\"d3a90575cb:w\"]" "photo":"[\"sizes\":[[\"s\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e2c\"]" "photo":"[\"fLWDQck0GGU\"]" "photo":"[56]" "photo":"[75]]" "photo":"[[\"m\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e2d\"]" "photo":"[\"TdcVw-PTrZ0\"]" "photo":"[97]" "photo":"[130]]" "photo":"[[\"x\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e2e\"]" "photo":"[\"E3C8Buuazz8\"]" "photo":"[453]" "photo":"[604]]" "photo":"[[\"y\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e2f\"]" "photo":"[\"Sg1QDLFZKbI\"]" "photo":"[605]" "photo":"[807]]" "photo":"[[\"z\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e30\"]" "photo":"[\"cx9R87nsiaA\"]" "photo":"[810]" "photo":"[1080]]" "photo":"[[\"w\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e31\"]" "photo":"[\"Vv28eWrIiAY\"]" "photo":"[1200]" "photo":"[1600]]" "photo":"[[\"o\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e32\"]" "photo":"[\"RrSUaPQfbp4\"]" "photo":"[130]" "photo":"[173]]" "photo":"[[\"p\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e33\"]" "photo":"[\"9Y9oyH6Gqok\"]" "photo":"[200]" "photo":"[267]]" "photo":"[[\"q\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e34\"]" "photo":"[\"hWhThkZIwBM\"]" "photo":"[320]" "photo":"[427]]" "photo":"[[\"r\"]" "photo":"[\"638518002\"]" "photo":"[\"78e35\"]" "photo":"[\"MR4kkUA21RQ\"]" "photo":"[510]" "photo":"[680]]]" "photo":"[\"kid\":\"973e1fa0db673b36d800371b81800000\"]" "photo":"[\"debug\":\"xswmwxwywzwwwowpwqwrw\"]"
}, {
"key": "server",
"value": "638518"
}, {
"key": "v",
"value": "5.67"
}]
}
}
```

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: «получаю такие данные» — любой JSON-парсер вернёт вам значение `photo` как строку, эту строку и надо передавать в saveMessagesPhoto

Comment: @andreymal, я уже разобрался, в PHP `photo` был в корректной форме, а в Shell не получалось что-то